# Import Lightroom Adjustments

Tags: lightroom

I recently installed my System (Windows+Apps) on a new hard drive.
Now I imported the folders containing my RAW files but all the adjustments I made are not shown anymore on this new Lightroom installation.

I still have access to the old hard drive with the previous Lightroom installation (Filesystem access. I cannot boot/launch apps from it). Where can I find the RAW adjustments I made and how to I import them to my new Lightroom installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you import the catalog? If you want, you can export the metadata for each image from the previous Lightroom: Select the images --> Right click --> Metadata --> Save Metadata to File. Near RAW you should have an XMP file and all your adjustments will be automatically recognize in the new Lightroom.

Comment: That was it. I had to import the catalog instead of just the RAW folder

Comment: You may have additional things to move depending on what you used (presets, calibrations, templates, etc.). You may want to review this link: https://www.lightroomqueen.com/how-move-lightroom-to-new-computer/